# Performance issue in updating Hashkey using HASHBYTES 'SHA2_256' for huge volume of ~20 million

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a scenario wherein I need to update hash key value for nearly 20 million records. The hash key needs to be generated using nearly 70 attributes and will be used in frequent join conditions.

I am converting the `HASHBYTES` output to `NVARCHAR` and then updating the temp table which has nearly 20 million records. The update statement is taking 3+ hours to run.

```
UPDATE #TempSomeTable
SET HashKey = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',CONCAT(ISNULL(COL_1,'NA'),ISNULL(COL_2,'NA'),ISNULL(COL_3,'NA'),.....ISNULL(COL_70,'NA'))),2)
```

Here, the datatype of HashKey is `NVARCHAR(50)`.

Can anyone here suggest how the performance can be improved?

Few options I am looking at it:

1. Converting the temp table to a MEMORY OPTIMIZED table
2. Applying `ISNULL` somewhere before the `UPDATE` statement
3. Changing datatype from `NVARCHAR(50)` to `VARCHAR(50)` OR `BINARY(32)`
4. Instead of `UPDATE`, Write the data into a new temp table and derive hash key in `SELECT` while inserting the record into new table (memory optimized table may be instead of temp table)

Please help and feedback.

Comment: This is a very SQL Server specific question. The <sql> tag is intended for ANSI/ISO SQL.

Answer (score 1):

- Get a faster computer
- Do not use ONE update - find a way to split this into various updates, i.e. by range of primary key. Then you can issue those in parallel on multiple connections. If you have a 16 core machine, you can in theory split the update to 16 connections - though NOT on a temporary table, you will have to make it a GLOBAL temporary table (prefix ##) so all connections can see it (which is ok - give it a random name, i.e. a GUID and you are fine).

At the end, Hashbytes is serial as you use it (in an update) and is not the fastest out of necessity (it does quite a lot).